# Sandboxing features in Windows 11 Enterprise all fail to launch

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-edge, windows-sandbox, microsoft-defender

I work in IT, and often need a sandbox environment to check security issues in. Historically I have done this using Windows Sandbox or MS Edge Defender App Guard, but on my new PC neither seem to be working and they aren't giving me any good reason why not. The only common error is "0x8007000d" while MDAG also shows subcodes "0x00000001" and "0x0000000e" - neither system will launch, rather exiting with these messages:

[image: Windows Sandbox Error]

[image: MDAG Error 1] [image: MDAG Error 2]

I've tried `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealt`h without success (`sfc` said it found some corrupt files and fixed but behavior didn't change and subsequent scans came back healthy; `restorehealth` for `dism` required the wim file [`dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /Source:wim:"D:\sources\install.wim":1 /limitaccess` with the Enterprise 23h2 iso], but failed to fix the issue despite exiting successfully). The BIOS has no virtualization settings but task manager reports virtualization is enabled. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Virtualization Status]

- Surface Laptop Studio 2
- Intel i7-13800H
- 16GB RAM
- Windows 11 Enterprise 23h2 build 22631.3155 (stable, non-insider)

Comment: Do the windows update troubleshooter

Comment: `I work in IT` Try to escape brotendo

Comment: @Gantendo I just tried the troubleshooter; the only issue it detected was the WaaSMedicSvc was not started; starting it did not resolve the issues with sandboxing

Comment: Did you chkdsk? virtualpc / virtualbox / vmware an acceptable workaround? Often reinstalling Windows is faster than trying to diagnose stuff like this

Comment: The usual reason for error 0x8007000d is damaged Windows components. And as SFC has found problem(s), I suggest to do [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/) to ensure that Windows is in a stable shape.

Comment: "failed to fix the issue" - Post the log indicating what issues were caught, there can be related issues and unrelated issues, would help you identify the cause for this error.